# How to create a persistant state for Pinia + Quasar?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm using Pinia for state managment, and I want the state to persist when the page is refeshed.

I'm aware of two options:

1. Use a plugin. Vuex has a [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) plugin for this, and Pinia has [a similar plugin](https://github.com/Seb-L/pinia-plugin-persist) but it's still under development.
2. Use local storage. Luckily Quasar has a [LocalStorage plugin](https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/web-storage#introduction) which would be nice to use here. But I'm not sure how to integrate it with Pinia, thus the reason for this post.

I found a nice [tutorial](https://stephanlangeveld.medium.com/simple-local-storage-implementation-using-vue-3-vueuse-and-pinia-with-zero-extra-lines-of-code-cb9ed2cce42a) doing something similar with Pinia + [Vueuse](https://vueuse.org/).

And I tried adapting it to my needs with Pinia + TypeScript + Quasar LocalStorage Plugin as per below:

```
import { User } from 'firebase/auth';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { LocalStorage } from 'quasar';

type CreateMutable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: CreateMutable<T[P]> };

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
  state: () => ({
    // user: {} as CreateMutable<User>, // This was my previous non-persistent state
    user: LocalStorage.set('user', {}) as unknown as CreateMutable<User>, // This is my attempt at using LocalStorage persistent state
  }),
  actions: {
    setUser(userData: User) {
      this.user = userData;
    },
    setPhotoURL(photoURLData: string | null) {
      this.user.photoURL = photoURLData;
    },
  },
});
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

The state does not persist on page refresh.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To initialize the `user` state with Local Storage data, use Quasar's [`LocalStorage.getItem()`](https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/web-storage#localstorage-api), and default to an empty object:

```js
export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
  state: () => ({
    user: (LocalStorage.getItem('user') || {}) as CreateMutable<User>,
  }),
  ⋮
```

In the `setUser` action, call `LocalStorage.set()` to save the user data to Local Storage.

Since `user` is an object, clone the object instead of directly assigning it, so that the store does not unnecessarily retain a reference to external objects. If `userData` has nested properties, you can use Quasar's [`extend`](https://quasar.dev/quasar-utils/other-utils#-deep-copy-objects) to deep-copy the object:

```js
import { extend, LocalStorage } from 'quasar'

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
  ⋮
  actions: {
    setUser(userData: User) {
      const copyOfData = { ...userData }
      // or...
      const copyOfData = extend(true /* deep */, {}, userData)

      LocalStorage.set('user', copyOfData)
      this.user = copyOfData
    },
  }
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-quasar-localstorage?file=src/stores/user.ts)

Answer (score 2):

I actually use "vanilla localStorage" and had no issues with that.
I am not a big fan of to much libraries, for simple tasks (although for not using them for complicated tasks).
Whatever, I am a fan of VueUse, too. This function I have not used, but I could imagine.it makes things even easier.

### Vanilla localStorage

#### Set into local storage

`localStorage.setItem("myStorageKey", "My persisted values");`

#### Get from local storage

`localStorage.getItem("myStorageKey");`

### State Mutation

Apart from that, I have not tried to set the localStoreage direct into the state. That seems like a red flag to me, as you usually should not directly mutate a state. But I am not sure in this case. I usually prepopulate the state which hard coded data (or just empty) and then I would write an action, which sets the data into the state.

Answer (score 2):

There's [`quasar-v2-ssr-pinia`](https://github.com/TobyMosque/quasar-v2-ssr-pinia) repository created before Pinia has official Quasar support. I tried to add `pinia-plugin-persist` and `pinia-plugin-persistedstate` in [this PR](https://github.com/TobyMosque/quasar-v2-ssr-pinia/pull/6) but these Pinia plugins didnt work with Quasar SSR, so Toby pushed an examples of persisted state using Quasar' Cookies, SessionStorage and LocalStorage adopters.

Good news: it's working and you can use any of storage adopters for any store.

Bad news: there's no partial store persistent but only whole store. We can create separate store to persist all its content as a workaround.

I'm planning to publish Toby's code to NPM to install it instead of copying from examples.